# How to add column to dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm a beginner to "R", so this might embarrass me, but nonetheless:

How do I add a column to a dataframe?  Here is my attempt at adding a normally distributed dataset as a column to an empty dataframe:

```
e = rnorm(1000)
mydf <- data.frame()
mydf[["e"]] <- e
```

and it gives the error:

> Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "e", value = c(-1.09398526454771, 
>   :    replacement has 1000 rows, data has 0

This is the resource I used for this:  [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Adding_and_removing_columns_from_a_data_frame/).  I even tried converting to a vector using `mydf[["e"]] <- as.vector(e)`.  But this still fails.  Help?  thank you.

Comment: You don't need to create an empty data.frame.  Just do `mydf <- data.frame(e=e)`

Comment: OKay, thank you.  I'm a scientist so I want to dig deeper.  Why does it not work to add to an empty dataframe?

Comment: @Sother That's because in order to add a column to an existing data.frame, the data.frame must have at least as many rows as the length of the vector that you're attaching. If you try `mydf <- data.frame(matrix(NA,1000,1)); mydf$e <- e` it works. Your initialization of an empty data.frame with zero rows and zero columns is not allocating the necessary memory.